# Can't load WMS in QField from QField Cloud

Tags: wms, qfield

Qfield won't let me load WMS from QField cloud project. The WMS is working when opening the project from cloud in QGIS on my computer.
When trying to load the project in QField, it gives the error shown below. It appears that the issue happens is the packaging of the project from the cloud.

Could it have something to do with HTTPS?
Does someone know a workaround if that's so?

I have tried with QField on multiple Android devices.

[image]

Comment: Beta software generally has a vendor support site; try using that.

Comment: Is the service accessible to your android device (does a GetCapabilities request work in a browser)